# Are there any thread-safety concerns with nested Parallel.ForEach invocations?

Tags: c#, thread-safety, static-methods

Should I have any thread safety concerns if I were to pass a list to a static method which uses a Parallel.ForEach and update the objects in the list.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Fruit> fruitList = new List<Fruit>();
        fruitList.Add(new Fruit() { Name = "Apple", Active = false });
        fruitList.Add(new Fruit() { Name = "Orange", Active = false });
        fruitList.Add(new Fruit() { Name = "Strawberry", Active = false });

        Fruit.ApplyUpdate(fruitList);            
    }
}

public class Fruit
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public List<FruitSupplier> Suppliers { get; set; }

    public Fruit()
    {
        this.Suppliers = new List<FruitSupplier>();
    }

    public static void ApplyUpdate(List<Fruit> fruitList)
    {
        Parallel.ForEach(fruitList, fruit =>
        {
            //do some processing and set the active property for example
            if (fruit.Name != "Apple")
                fruit.Active = true;

            Parallel.ForEach(fruit.Suppliers, fruitSupplier =>
            { 
                //do some processing for the suppliers
                fruitSupplier.Name = "Fruits R Us";
            });
        });
    }
}

public class FruitSupplier
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string Country {get;set;}
}
```

I've edited the example to include nested Parallel.ForEach.  If we consider this Program Main() as a web service, the actual listg being passed to the ApplyUpdate() method isn't going to get modified by any other code, other than the two Parallel.ForEach.

Comment: Provided each `Fruit` object isn't shared by other threads, then your code is fine.

Comment: Does any other code modify that list in the same time?

Comment: As you're using a lambda function inside `Parallel.ForEach` you run the risk of accidentally creating a closure. You could aid thread-safety by promoting the callback to a static member function.

Comment: @Dai I've updated my question to include some more information.  Also the `Fruit` object isn't going to get changed outside of this thread